# $_SERVER me retorna ::1

Tags: php

Boa tarde!

Se eu no PHP der um `echo/var_dump/print_r`, etc... Em `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];`
OBS: Em local host, ele me retorna: `::1`

Por que disso? O que significa esse `::1`?

Comment: Significa localhost (127.0.0.1 ipv4) em ipv6.

Comment: Ele não consegue mostrar o 127.0.0.1? Não tem como mudar isso?